# Converting a bitmap to Gray8 with FormatConvertedBitmap only uses 4 bits?

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap

I have a BitmapSource (RGB) that I wish to convert to 8bpp grayscale. This is the code I use:

```
BitmapSource ConvertToGray8(BitmapSource bitmap)
{
    FormatConvertedBitmap newFormattedBitmapSource = new FormatConvertedBitmap();

    newFormattedBitmapSource.BeginInit();
    newFormattedBitmapSource.Source = bitmap;
    newFormattedBitmapSource.DestinationFormat = PixelFormats.Gray8;
    newFormattedBitmapSource.EndInit();

    return newFormattedBitmapSource;
}
```

However, if I look at the resulting bytes, I get something like this:

```
66 66 66 66 77 ff ff ee ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ee ff ff ff 00 00 00 11 00 00 00 ff
ff dd ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff bb 88 88 88 88 ff ff ff ff 99 88 88 88 aa ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff dd ff 88 00 ff ff 22 ff ff 00 88 ff dd ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff dd ff ff cc 66 66 66 66 66 aa ff ff dd ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
ff ff dd ff ff 33 00 11 11 11 00 22 ff ff dd ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 77 88
```

It would seem that only 4 bits are used to convert (i.e. 0x0-0xF), and then they are repeated to make 8 bits (i.e. 0x00-0xFF). The result is an 8-bit image with 16 grayscale levels.

Any clues? I would like to try to avoid converting by hand, if possible. I'm mostly curious why its converting like this.

Edit:

- Input file (BGR32): [colors.bmp](http://psignoret.com/forever/colors.bmp)
- Output file with PixelFormats.Gray8: [colors_g8.gmp](http://psignoret.com/forever/colors_g8.bmp)
- Output file with PixelFormats.Gray32Float: [colors_g32f.bmp](http://psignoret.com/forever/colors_g32f.bmp)

I also used [the project](http://wrb.home.xs4all.nl/Articles_2010/Article_WPFPixelFormats_01/Solution_BitmapPixFormat_07.zip.) shown on [this article](http://wrb.home.xs4all.nl/Articles_2010/Article_WPFPixelFormats_01.htm) with the same results. I'm starting to think that there is no real 8bpp grayscale (at least as far as BMPs are concerned) and it has something to do with indexing. Will look into this later today and update if anything new comes up. Using this same project, the 8bpp TIFFs seem to save correctly.

Comment: What are the color values in the original image? Is it possible that they all happen to actually average out to these values? If all of the original colors are "web-safe" colors [which are multiples of 0x33], and they're arithmetically averaged, the results will all be multiples of 0x11

Comment: That's a good point, and I wish it were true, it would have been a brilliant reason. Alas, I tried with many different variations of BMPs and none worked. I'll edit with links to my source and output images, as well as a C# project that causes the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The value FF for example is 4 + 4 = 8 bits. It's not that only four bits are being used for conversion but rather bytes are displayed as HEX digits which requires minimum 4 bits to be together. So, each byte in the data is being **displayed** as two HEX digits separated by spaces.

I guess, each byte value corresponds to a variant of gray color in a 256 color scale. So perhaps when your image is passed through the 256 color scale it reduces to the corresponding 16 gray colors rather than a separate 8 bit gray scale.

You can read about how each color value of the image is weighed in grayscale, [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale) & [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-bit_color).

Comment: He's talkign about the fact that there aren't any values like "7E".

Comment: No variant of Gray color can have a value like "7E" in a 256 color scale.

Comment: In a 256 _gray_ scale, which is his destination format, they can have _any_ value. (my first comment was before your edit. I've removed my downvote.) This still doesn't account for converting values that were originally color, except for specialized 256 color palettes that reduce to a limited number of grays (such as color cubes)

Comment: @Random832's replies are correct, according to [MSDN docs for PixelFormats.Gray8 property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pixelformats.gray8.aspx): "Gets the Gray8 pixel format which displays an 8 bits-per-pixel grayscale channel, allowing 256 shades of gray."